# Get the ID of the group to which the node is added

Tags: group

Using Drupal 8 with the Group module, I have an action that is run via hook_node_insert that needs to know the group id of the group that the node is added to.

Im using this code to get the group id of the group(s) that the node is a member of:

```
function get_groups_from_node($nid) {
  $group_ids = array();
  $ids = \Drupal::entityQuery('group_content')
    ->condition('entity_id', $nid)
    ->execute();

  $relations = \Drupal\group\Entity\GroupContent::loadMultiple($ids);
  foreach ($relations as $rel) {
    if ($rel->getEntity()->getEntityTypeId() == 'node') {
      $group_ids[] = $rel->getGroup()->id();      
    }
  }
  
  return $group_ids;
}
```

When I feed the nid of an existing group node into the function, it works, but not for the newly created ones that are cought by the hook.

```
function mymodule_hook_node_insert (NodeInterface $node) {     
  
  $nid = $node->nid->value;  
  $groups = get_groups_from_node($nid);

}
```

The information does not seem to be available at the time of node creation - I guess the hook fires before the node is actually added to a group?

Should I use another hook, or is there a better way?

Comment: Does it throw an error?

Comment: no, it just returns NULL. if i run the function on the same node manually later, it returns the groupid.

Comment: Take the hook out of the function name and clear cache. Does $node->id() also return null?

Comment: no, node->nid->value returns its value just fine
what do you mean "take the hook out"? I don't understand - then the function would not run, no?

Comment: Instead of using the `nid`, your function should use the `Node` itself and dig into the field values without using an entity query

Comment: getting the nid is not the problem, that works just fine.

Comment: Yep it's not the problem but since your entity query which "works just fine" doesn't work on node creation, you should better dig into the `Node` field values. By the way there's absolutely no reason to make another query when you have all the needed informations in the `Node` itself which is the entity avalaible in the hook you're using.

Comment: are you sure the information about group membership is included in the Node field values? because i could not find anything about group there

Comment: It depends how you manage your groups & content. In my case it's not stored directly in the node, it's a taxonomy term's field which store the group id and the node is related to the taxonomy term. In such case you need to load the taxonomy term related to the node and get the group field value from the loaded term.

Comment: im using the Drupal group module